# JavaScript jQuery animate doesn't work, every other effect works well

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I really don't know what is the problem with the animate,
and it's just the animate because every other effect that I am trying to check works well:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#box1").animate({left: '250px'});
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
      .box{
        border: 2px solid black;
        width:100px;
        height: 100px;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 20px;
        margin: 5px;
      }

      p{
        font-family: Arial;
        color: aquamarine;
        font-size: 30px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id="he"><center>New website</center></h1>
    <p id="pp">Hey what's up?</p>
    <button id="butt">click here</button>
    <div id="box1" class="box">box9</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you haven't defined any `position` attr for your `#box1`

Answer (score 1):

Give a position to the `box` and it will work.

Code below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("#box1").animate({
      left: '250px'
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
}
p {
  font-family: Arial;
  color: aquamarine;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="he"><center>New website</center></h1>
<p id="pp">Hey what's up?</p>
<button id="butt">click here</button>
<div id="box1" class="box">box9</div>
```

Comment: **+1** 
@Ish yes its works when i give it a position..
but why is it?

Comment: Because, `left/right/bottom/top` attributes are related to the position of the *DOM* element if you don't defined the position as `relative/fixed/absolute` then they don't have any effect on it and kinda worthless to declare.

Comment: `left` works for a 'positioned' element only i.e. if position is anything other than `static` (which is default by the way)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#box1").animate({"left": "250px"});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
         $("#box1").animate({'left': '250px','position':"absolute"});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

your animation made it wrongly. at first you may specify the position. the div box should be position absolute. then the left value should 0.

here the css code:.

```
 .box{
        border: 2px solid black;
        width:100px;
        height: 100px;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 20px;
        margin: 5px;
        position:absolute;
        left:0;
    }
```

Now you try it will animate.